# How to add custom font into imglyKit SDK in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, imgkit

I have tried the following code for adding custom fonts into imglyKit SDK but no custom font is added. I have also put .ttf file into info.plist file as a resource.

```
        let sampleImage = image.image

    let configuration = Configuration() { builder in
        FontImporter.init().importFonts()

        builder.configurePhotoEditorViewController({ (editPhotoOption) in

            editPhotoOption.allowedPhotoEditorActions = [.text]

            editPhotoOption.actionButtonConfigurationClosure = {cell, _ in

                cell.captionLabel.text = "Add Text"
                //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
            editPhotoOption.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
            editPhotoOption.allowsPreviewImageZoom = false            
        })

        builder.configureToolStackController({ (toolStackOption) in

            toolStackOption.mainToolbarBackgroundColor = UIColor.red
            toolStackOption.secondaryToolbarBackgroundColor = UIColor.brown

        })

        builder.configureTextFontToolController({ (textFontToolOption) in

            var fontArray = [String]()
            fontArray = ["AlexBrush_Regular.ttf", "Arabella.ttf"]
            textFontToolOption.accessibilityElements = fontArray

            textFontToolOption.actionButtonConfigurationClosure = { cell, _ in
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }                
        })


        builder.configureTextToolController({ (textToolOption) in

            textToolOption.textViewConfigurationClosure = { label in

                label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            }
        })
    }

    let photoEditViewController = PhotoEditViewController(photo: sampleImage!, configuration: configuration)



    let toolStackController = ToolStackController(photoEditViewController: photoEditViewController)
    toolStackController.delegate = self
    toolStackController.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    present(toolStackController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

please help me to add a custom font

I have also used FontImporter class to load custom font as per guide here  http://static.photoeditorsdk.com/docs/ios/Classes/FontImporter.html 
Thanks...

Comment: Do you have sample project?

Comment: yes @TimurBernikowich

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've investigate this issue. Looks like `importFonts()` function is added only for internal usage. In case you'd like to add custom fonts you should ask `imglyKit` developers or you can swizzle `availableFontsList` method to add your custom fonts.

You can find this method in class [InstanceFactory on GitHub](https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-ios/blob/d4e96d868b211962218477adaf931af75f98b7d2/imglyKit/Backend/IMGLYInstanceFactory.swift). Class methods swizzling sample: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ivanbruel/f098c465e0ebae444f63)

Comment: availableFontsList property is read only we can not assign value @TimurBernikowich

Comment: But you can swizzle getter method while there is no another way @SubhashKhimani